# Service for identifying an un-tagged mp3

Tags: web-services, mp3, id3, audio-fingerprinting

Is there an open source service that I can call from a program, where it passes information about a un-tagged mp3, and it responds with details about the song(e.g. artist, album, track, etc.)?  If not, is there an alternative I can use to identify songs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MusicBrainz](http://musicbrainz.org/) is one that works pretty well.  It uses an "acoustic fingerprint" to look up potential matches.

Answer (score 1):

[AcoustID](http://acoustid.org/) is an open source fingerprint system that matches fingerprints with data from [MusicBrainz](http://musicbrainz.org/)

See http://musicbrainz.org/doc/Fingerprinting for details and a list of other figerprinting systems.